# What are the similarities and differences between Reiatsu and Chakra?

Tags: naruto, bleach

What are the similarities and difference between Reiatsu from *Bleach* and Chakra from *Naruto*?

I've felt that they both are similar, like it's a part of the individuals' insides/spirit/soul and also it can be sensed from a distance. Generally, the higher the person's Reiatsu or Chakra levels, the stronger that person is. Another similarity is how Chakra and Reiatsu diminishes to zero while dying. However, there are some significant differences which don't make them the same thing with different names.

I want to know both the differences and the similarities between them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, one of the main differences is most likely that chakra in *Naruto* seems to be a power exclusive to living things (like animals, plants and humans) while reiatsu in *Bleach* is more of a general form of energy (as all of Seireitei is made of reishi). Also, chakra can only be used through a medium (a body, tool etc.) while reishi can just be collected from outside and then used (like the way quincies collect reishi to form their arrows)

Also, later in *Naruto*, Madara explains that

> chakra was not actually a power of humans. They "stole" it from the God Tree (神樹, Shinju), which then became the Ten-Tails. And the Sage of the Six Paths inherited chakra from his mother, defeated the Ten-Tails and gave chakra to living things as a mean to connect each others hearts. Only later they started to refuse to connection to each other, and instead train their own chakra to use it in battle. So while reiatsu is a ever present form of energy, chakra is more of a foreign power to humans

In my personal opinion, I think that reiatsu is a symbol of "the power of one's Soul" while chakra is "the power of one's body".

Comment: also note that the translated words tha replace Reatsu is Spiritual PRESSURE, because when released, it exerts pressure on people around it. Enough of it can slow down weaker opponents, Damage your own body if its not strong enough (ichigo when he first got bankai), paralyze really weak opponents (aizen did this to ichigos friends), or even erase the existence of things or even regular humans (aizen again). Also, everything in the soul society is made Reshi, which can be directly converted into Reatsu (primarialy by Quincies)